# How to prune some unnecessary branches from the Voronoi diagram?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, voronoi

I generated the Voronoi diagram using the following MATLAB code. The problem is that in the output image I obtain some useless lines that I want to remove. By useless lines, I mean like those circled in purple, so the lines that are directly attached to the polygons. I would like only the ones in green in the output image. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
clc; clear all; close all;

%% Input Map
RGB = imread('mappa3.png');
figure('Position',[100 0 600 700],'color','k')
imagesc(RGB);
axis image
title('Input Map','color','w');
axis off
set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
hold off;

%% Convert to binary image
I = rgb2gray(RGB);
binaryImage = im2bw(RGB, 0.3);
sz  = size(binaryImage);

%% Pose
% Initial Pose
xs = 270; ys = 296; % valori iniziali 55 e 33
% Goal Pose
xg = 50; yg = 50; % valori iniziali 50 e 50
% Pose Matrix
pose = zeros(sz(1),sz(2));
pose(ys,xs) = 1;
pose(yg,xg) = 1;

%% Voronoi Road Map
figure('Position',[100 0 600 700],'color','k');
hold on;
set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
sk = 1;
for i = 1:sz(1)
  for j = 1:sz(2)
    if(binaryImage(i,j) == 1 )
      xv(sk) = j;
      yv(sk) = i;
      sk = sk+1;
    end
  end
end
[vrx,vry]  = voronoi(xv,yv);
set(gca,'YDir','Reverse');
plot(xv,yv,'y.',vrx,vry,'b-')
axis tight
%axis([1 sz(2) 1 sz(1) ]) ;
axis image
title({'Voronoi Road Map';'* - Represents Starting and Goal Position '},'color','w');
axis off

spy(pose,'*r')
```

[image: mappa3.png]

[image: output image]

Comment: A voronoi diagram has very specific definition, if you remove those things, then the resul is not a voronoi diagram. Also, how yould you remove them/connect the mesh? its not clear at all how the solution would look like

Comment: Consider using `imshow` instead of `imagesc`, it'll do most of the necessary things for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking each individual pixel as a cell centroid, so the Voronoi diagram encircles each individual pixel. You want to take each group of connected pixels (polygon) as a centroid. And on top of that, somehow include the size of these groups of pixels so that the Voronoi diagram doesn't cut though them.

You can accomplish all of this by computing the skeleton of the background, like so:

```matlab
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbmKp.png');
background = img(:,:,1)==0;
voronoi = bwskel(background,'MinBranchLength',1e6);
```

[image]

Comment: What a fantastically simple answer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I know! I used to give this as a homework exercise to my students… :D

Comment: @CrisLuengo your solution seems to be brilliant! Thanks. However my code with your modifications does not run. In which part of my code should I past your modifications and what do I have to write in the plot to get the image you have pasted here?

Comment: @Gargolla9 I ignored your code, the code I posted is self-contained. `voronoi` is an image, you can do `imshow(voronoi)` to see it. I did an overlay of the `voronoi` image on the input image to show the results.

Comment: @CrisLuengo it is clear, thank you. My only question is, with your code (which is different from mine) how it is possible to find the shortest trajectory between any starting and ending point?

Comment: @CrisLuengo in my code the shorthest path corresponds to the 'Roboth Path' section. Please any suggestion?

Comment: @Gargolla9 That's a new question, you should post it as a new (self-contained) question

Comment: @Gargolla9 The shortest path problem is a different one, and does not depend on a Voronoi diagram. You want to create a graph containing all the background pixels, then apply Dijkstra's algorithm to that. You can adjust edge weights according to the distance to your obstacles, if you need to keep your path far away from obstacles.